# Switch between sites in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add multi language support to my Wordpress website. I activated Network function in Wordpress as it says [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network). And I created a second site for french language. Everything is fine and working properly. Now I have two websites like `http://example.com/` and `http://example.com/fr`. What I want is to switch from my first site to second and back whit a language indicator like flag. Is there any plugin which allows switching between two sites in a Wordpress network?

Comment: have you tried this plugin? https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-language-switcher/

Comment: yes I have tried this plugin, but this will create a page with translated text on the same site. I don't want to translate any text, I have already translated text. All I want to do is switch between sites, like if I am on the page http://example.com/?p=123 on the main site, switch site link should take me to the same page on the second page, like http://example.com/fr/?p=123.